# issue to detect first matching end of string with regex

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I try to find the string starting with "start" and ending with one of this strings : (, | . | finish) with skipping "finish" when its followed by a "not" or "here".

Here is the example :

```
CONF: For this charaxter start 6 years of  this Revision 01 its indicated in the house warranty  not finish for  received days  completion. affected you. of your face
```

for this i used the following regex :

```
(start|START).*(?!not finish|here)(?=[.]|[,]|finish)
```

link for my try : [https://regex101.com/r/USaH6I/1](https://regex101.com/r/mLEbwG/1)

requested return is :

```
start 6 years of  this Revision 01 its indicated in the house warranty  not finish for  received days completion
```

but I got :

```
start 6 years of  this Revision 01 its indicated in the house warranty  not finish for  received days completion, affected you
```

Comment: Why doesn't the expected output finish at the first comma (after `Revision 01`)?

Comment: oups i have to delete the comma after 01 in the link provided sorry, thanks

Comment: Does `(?i)start.*?(?<!not|here)(?<!not\s)(?<!here\s)(?=\.|finish)` help (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xJQNo4/1))?

Answer (score 0):

If you meant skipping matching if 'here' or 'not' is found after 'finish' then try this: `(?:start|START).*?(?=[.]|[,]|(finish (?!here|not)))`

Test here: https://regex101.com/r/PaXBKL/1

If you meant skipping matching if 'here' or 'not' is found before 'finish' then try this: `(?:start|START).*?(?=[.]|[,]|((?<!here|not) finish))`

These follow your condition of stopping when , or . is found.

Cases:

When 'finish' is found first :

> CONF: For this charaxter **start 6 years of  this Revision 01 its
> indicated in the house warranty  not finish** for  received days finish
> here completion. affected you. of your face

When 'finish' if followed by 'here'/'not' it will skip till a `,` or `.` is found:

> CONF: For this charaxter **start 6 years of  this Revision 01 its
> indicated in the house warranty  not for  received days finish here
> completion**. affected you. of your face
>
> CONF: For this charaxter **start 6 years of  this Revision 01 its
> indicated in the house warranty finish not for**, received days here
> completion. affected you. of your face

Comment: proposed solution works in absence of finding dot(.) for exemple after "here" , this must be skipped , maybe it was not clear in description but also when finding "here[.]" must be skipped : https://regex101.com/r/SlCjrU/1 ,  MUST not stop at "here." but at "completion."